# How to get All documents from Firestore in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I had been trying multiple solutions to get all documents from Firebase Firestore. I am working on iOS part, I even added google plist file in iOS project but cannot get back data. Firestore says its been hit multiple times but when it comes to results I see nothing.

here is code I am using:

```
async function getAnnouncements() {
  const usersCollection = await firestore().collection('Announcements').get();
  console.log(usersCollection);
}
```

Comment: `async function getAnnouncements() {
    const usersCollection = await firebase.firestore().collection('Announcements').get();
    console.log(usersCollection.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
}`
can you try this?

Comment: `[]` result is empty

Comment: I have provided an answer below.please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [document](https://aboutreact.com/react-native-firebase-cloud-firestore-db/#pagesViewAllUserjs) it  should be called as a promise not just as a function.

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
async function getAnnouncements() {

const usersCollection = await firestore().collection('Users').get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
           /*
            A QuerySnapshot allows you to inspect the collection,
            such as how many documents exist within it,
            access to the documents within the collection,
            any changes since the last query and more.
        */

        querySnapshot.forEach((documentSnapshot) => {
          console.log('elements: ', documentSnapshot);
          });
      });
}
```